# reactjs passing array of components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass an array of components to another components and render them after adding other props

```
import {ComponentB} from ".../ComponentB";


<ComponentA 
    list={[
       <ComponentB title={'title 1'} />,
       <ComponentB title={'title 2'} />,
       <ComponentB title={'title 3'} />
    ]} />
```

How to loop over `list` props in `ComponentA` ?
this doesn't work :

// ComponentA

```
    { list.map((Item, index) => {
        return (
            <Item otherProps={'value xxx'}/>
        )
    })}
```

this yes but cannot add props

```
    { list.map((Item, index) => {
        return (
            {Item}
        )
    })}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, before `// ComponentA`, you have done `var list = this.props.list`?  Otherwise, that `list` var is undefined.

Comment: list is defined, it's component props that i get in function declaration. i l will edit code:)

Comment: Go with the answer below -- you may want to pass a component instance, but a component itself?  Probably not.

Comment: yes, i was trying to pass the components itself as we can do and use with props.children

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass just the component, don't invoke the component in the parent: that way, the `ComponentA` can invoke the component with all the needed props:

```
<ComponentA 
    list={[
       { Comp: ComponentB, title: 'title 1' },
       { Comp: ComponentB, title: 'title 2' },
       { Comp: ComponentB, title: 'title 3' },
    ]}
/>
```

```
// ComponentA
{ list.map(
  ({ Comp, title }, index) => <Comp title={title} otherProps={'value'} />
)}
```

Comment: thanks this work. is there a way to avoid the json object declaration in list `{ Comp: ComponentB, title: 'title 1' }`  with `<Comp param1 param2 .... />` ?

Comment: There's [no such thing as a [JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - this is just an array of objects, no JSON involved. You could use an array of arrays instead if you wanted, or if you know the components are all going to be the same, you could pass that as a separate prop and then have an array of titles.

Answer (score 0):

another approche is to use children props and iterate over it :

```
<ComponentA>      
   <ComponentB title={'title 1'} />
   <ComponentB title={'title 2'} />
   <ComponentB title={'title 3'} />
</ComponentA>
```

// in componentA

```
 export function componentA({children}){
      let paramA = 'XYZ' ; 
      return (
            <div>
                {children?.map((child, i) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={i}>
                        {React.cloneElement(child, {paramA })}
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
            </div>
      )

    }
```

but i don't kwow if cloning is expensive